# C#.NET XMPP over HTTP without third party library

Tags: c#, .net, http, xmpp, ejabberd

I have the one XMPP server. I does not know which XMPP server is running there.

I only have the XMPP URL, Port, UserName and Password.

So, I have to create the application that only listen/received the message sent to the my UserName in C#.NET without the using the of the third party XMPP library.

I tried the [jabber-net](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jabber-net/) library, in which I successfully received the messages, but I have to do it without any third party library.

How can I implement the XMPP client in the C#.NET without third party library?

Answer (score 0):

You should read XMPP standard for implementation client for your own. But you can use third-party library.
I'm using Artalk.Xmpp library and work good.
This repository contains an easy-to-use and well-documented .NET assembly for communicating with an XMPP server. It supports basic Instant Messaging and Presence functionality as well as a variety of XMPP extensions.
https://github.com/araditc/Artalk.Xmpp